# Switch in a function

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I am supposed to build a simple function where a character's level determines their health.
so:

- It returns the number 100 if level is 0
- It returns the number 150 if level is 1
- It returns the number 180 if level is 2
- It returns the number 190 if level is 3

Using a switch function, I want to say if case is 0, then determineHP is 100. Here is my code thus far:

```
var determineHP = function(Number) {

  switch (determineHP) {
    case 0:
      console.log(determineHP(0) === 100);
      break;
    case 1:
      console.log(determineHP(1) === 150);
      break;
    case 2:
      console.log(determineHP(2) === 180);
      break;
    case 3:
      console.log(determineHP(3) === 190);
  }
}
```

Obviously this is not correct, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you recall your function?

Comment: the easiest way is to store the level and health values in a map and do a simple lookup.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What exactly is happening with your code?  I'm a little confused with you using ```determineHP``` in your switch.   It gives me Inception vibes.

Comment: If you want to `switch`, you want to `switch (Number)`, and `case 0: return 100`. Not whatever recursive contortions you are doing there.

Answer (score 1):

## With switch case

```js
function getHp(level) {
  switch (level) {
  case 0:
    return 100
  case 1:
    return 150
  case 2:
    return 180
  case 3:
    return 190
  }
}

console.log(getHp(1))
```

## With stored array

Because levels are starting from 0 and incrementing with one, you can just make an array

```js
const hpAmounts = [100,150,180,190];
let level = 1;

console.log(hpAmounts[level])
```

## With objects

If you want to store more information, consider working with objects

```js
const data = [
  {
    level: 0,
    hp: 100,
    damage: 10
  },
  {
    level: 1,
    hp: 150,
    damage: 10
  },
  {
    level: 2,
    hp: 180,
    damage: 10
  },
  {
    level: 3,
    hp: 190,
    damage: 10
  }
]

let level = 1;

console.log(data.find(d => d.level === level).hp)
```